# No shadow-root found in Polymer component but works, why?

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

Polymer uses a Shadow DOM for its components as found at [docs](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom).

Im investigating a very basic example of Hello-World in github:
https://github.com/webcomponents/hello-world-polymer

Im inspecting the [demo](http://webcomponents.github.io/hello-world-polymer/bower_components/hello-world-polymer/) and **I cant find any shadow-root**.

I have worked with Polymer and I have used the `shadow-root` before, but why theres no `shadow-root` for this component? Because of some optimizations?

Comment: You are reading the doc for Polymer 3 while the example is a Polymer 1 element that didn't use Shadow DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `shadow-root` because they use the polyfilled Shadow DOM for v0 spec and not the current one supported by the browsers (v1).

The demo you provided was built with Polymer 1 (according to `hello-world.html` source code since it uses `Polymer()` function and the deprecated HTML imports). Polymer 1 was built on top of Web Components v0 specs (Custom Elements v0, Shadow DOM v0 and HTML Imports) which are now deprecated and replaced by Shadow DOM v1 and Custom Elements v1.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I see additional info can be found here https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom